# jquery find all elements with class and return the count position of the clicked Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not looking for `$(this).index()` as an FYI.  So, what I have are two `<ul>` tags with `<li>` tags within them.  I want to know which `<ul>` was clicked and which `<li>` was clicked.  For example something like ul 0 and li 3. So if there are 10 `<ul>` tags on the page I only want to look at the ones with the `list` class for clicks.

jQuery Example that will not work for what I want:

```js
$('ul').click(function(event) {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul class="list">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

The wanted outcome of the clicked element:
UL # and LI #.  Like UL0 LI3, UL1 LI3, etc...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cg3a8d6n/

Comment: The index you are looking at is the UL not the li.

Comment: @epascarello I am looking for both in a sense.  I need the total number of UL-s with class list.  Then once a person clicks one - I need to return which one.  And on top of it which li in the ul.  So, If there are 4 UL tags with a class of list and the user clicks the third one and the second li in it it would spit out UL3 LI2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use click event on `li` element and then get its index and also the index of its parent which is `ul`. You can also specify selector inside the `index` method to consider only specific elements that match the selector.

```js
$('ul.list li').click(function(event) {
  const li = $(this).index();
  const ul = $(this).parent().index('ul.list');
  console.log(`ul: ${ul} li: ${li}`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul></ul>
<ul></ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yep, that is it.  Thanks!  Will accept when the time limit is reached.  Thanks again!